# Which statistical test for comparing ratios of independent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have two conditions: A and B. Under each condition two parameters were measured in triplicates: x and y. Both are independent from each other (meaning the first x value does not experimentally correspond to the first y value) and I do not know the distribution of their populations. Now I want to compare the ratio x/y between both conditions A and B. Which statistical test could/should I use to decide on discarding the null-hypothesis that the ratios would be the same?

Comment: Could you clarify the situation more? In statistics, parameters cannot be measured. Also, are $x$ and $y$ 3-dimensional vectors? Are elements within $x$ or $y$ correlated?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology. This is a biological experiment. For each condition (A and B) I have 6 samples (test tubes). I use 3 of them to measure one thing (x) and the 3 remaining to measure something else (y). I cannot measure both things with the same sample since the experimental setup does not allow this. I hope this makes things more clear?